# Moving iis7 to another server. Generic 503 error

Tags: iis-7

**I was moving iis to another server and I get a generic service unavailable 503 error. When looking at this error in the log:**
IISMANAGER_ERROR_LOADING_PROVIDER_TYPE

IIS Manager could not load type 'Microsoft.Web.Management.PlatformInstaller.Server.PlatformInstallerModuleProvider, Microsoft.Web.Management.PlatformInstaller.Server, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35' for module provider 'PlatformInstaller' that is declared in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config. Verify that the type is correct, and that the assembly that contains the module provider is in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

Exception:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Management.PlatformInstaller.Server, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Web.Management.PlatformInstaller.Server, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.AdministrationModuleProvider.GetModuleProvider(String userName, String connectionName)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Process:InetMgr
Connection:VPS2837\VPS2837Admin

**Any suggestions? I have tried finding a replacing the C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\administration.config   file with 5.0.0.0 instead of 4.0.0.0 for the version of Microsoft web management. Still no luck. Thanks in advice**

Comment: Did you install Web Platform Installer on the new server?
http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: Yes, Version 5.0 ... But interesting it doesn't show in the management section of iis. Is this a big concern?

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling it, and check that it shows up?

Comment: THANK YOU!!! After uninstalling , then re-installing I was able to see the MS Web Platform in iis. This got rid of the error as posted above. A different error came up which was solved by resting the app pool user password and now Im UP! Thank You so much, you saved me hours!!!